# How much does a used Gibson Flying V guitar( not strung) all the way, cost?

Tags: guitar

I was given a Gibson Flying V acoustic guitar made in India or Japan i forget which one, but it was from a family member of a deceased neighbor, but it is not all the way strung. How much does this type of guitar go for if it's not all the way strung...?

Comment: Whether or not it has all the strings is irrelevant to its value. Putting new strings on a guitar is cheap and easy. I don't think we answer this kind of question here. You can look around for an appraisal. You'll want to find the serial number for the guitar. If it's actually Gibson guitar, it will have a serial number stamped into the back of the headstock. If there is no serial number there, then either the guitar has been altered or it wasn't a Gibson to begin with. As far as I know, Gibson has not had factories in Japan or India. They do make the Epiphone brand in Korea, I believe.

Comment: If the guitar was made in India or Japan, then it's not a Gibson. Other companies have approximated the shape of a flying v in an acoustic model, but not Gibson.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because any answer will quickly grow out of date.

Comment: @Aaron I think the answer will go out of date only if Gibson starts manufacturing acoustic Flying Vs in India or Japan, and I don't think that will happen any time soon

Comment: The number of strings still on the guitar makes absolutely no difference when it comes to value. It's a bit like whether it's had a recent oil change. Value does go up and down based on fashion, so auction sites like Reverb are better for these questions than this group.

Comment: People who closed this: is there an imaginable trend where a guitar that is in unplayable condition and has obviously fake brand would gain value?